# How to serialize/deserialize "splashed" complex type?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I'm connecting to external XML API and I'm trying to parse it to POJOs using Jackson `XmlMapper` class. Part of the XML looks like this:

```
<invoice>
    <some>element</some>
    <some_other>element</some_other>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <cost>10.42</cost>
    <breakdown>
        <item id="1">
            <description>blah blah</description>
            <cost>4.21</cost>
        </item>
    </breakdown>
</invoice>
```

And I want to parse the `currency` and `cost` elements in a single `Money` object.

Worse yet, the inner `item`s only specify the cost and "reuse" the currency code. Can I parse them in some intelligent way using Jackson?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to parse the currency and cost elements in a single Money object.

Given the XML provided, you can parse the `currency` and `cost` elements in to a single `Money` object by creating a value object for the invoice and utilizing [`@JsonUnwrapped`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html).

### Create a Value Object for the Invoice

If you do not want to create an object for the invoice, you could instead configure your `XmlMapper` to ignore unknown properties, and deserialize the entire response into the `Money` object. Creating a separate class for your invoice is a cleaner approach in my opinion.

The purpose of creating an `Invoice` object is to encapsulate all of the elements of the response. Right now you may only need `currency` and `cost`, but later you may want access to the `breakdown` for example. The object could be structured like this:

```
public class Invoice {
    private final String some;
    private final String some_other;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private final Money money;
    private final List<Item> breakdown;

    @JsonCreator
    public Invoice(@JsonProperty("some") String some,
                   @JsonProperty("some_other") String some_other,
                   @JsonProperty("money") Money money,
                   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item") List<Item> breakdown) {
        this.some = some;
        this.some_other = some_other;
        this.money = money;
        this.breakdown = breakdown;
    }

    public String getSome() {
        return some;
    }

    public String getSome_other() {
        return some_other;
    }

    public Money getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    public List<Item> getBreakdown() {
        return breakdown;
    }
}
```

Notice that the `Money` property is annotated with `@JsonUnwrapped`. This can be on the field, inside the constructor, or on a setter and it will "unwrap" the `Money` object and deserialize its members on the same level as `Invoice`'s. Structure your class like this to deserialize currency and cost into a single object:

```
public class Money {
    private final String currency;
    private final Double cost;

    @JsonCreator
    public Money(@JsonProperty("currency") String currency,
                 @JsonProperty("cost") Double cost) {
        this.currency = currency;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public Double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

> the inner items only specify the cost and "reuse" the currency code.

### Separating `Money` and "item" Models if Possible

Reusing the `Money` object for two different models is less ideal then having an abject to represent each view. For example, a `Money` object for `currency` and `cost`, and an `Item` object for `id`, `description`, and `cost`. If this is possible in your project, I would create an object like this for "item":

```
public class Item {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public final String id;
    public final String description;
    public final Double cost;

    @JsonCreator
    public Item(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                @JsonProperty("description") String description,
                @JsonProperty("cost") Double cost) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

### Reusing `Money` for "item" Values

If you do not have the liberty to create a new object and need to reuse `Money`, you can configure your `XmlMapper` to ignore unknown properties and put all of the properties on the `Money` object.

#### Configure `XmlMapper` to Ignore Unknown Properties

I recommend extending `XmlMapper` like so:

```
public class CustomXmlMapper extends XmlMapper {
    public CustomXmlMapper() {
        configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }
}
```

#### Add All Possible Properties to `Money`

This will populate the properties when ever the elements are present. For example, when an "item" is deserialized: `id`, `description`, and `cost` will be populated and `currency` will be null.

```
public class Money {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public final String id;
    public final String description;
    private final String currency;
    private final Double cost;

    @JsonCreator
    public Money(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                 @JsonProperty("description") String description,
                 @JsonProperty("currency") String currency,
                 @JsonProperty("cost") Double cost) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public Double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```